# Implement a trait that changes a type from sqlx to an enum I created

Tags: rust, refactoring, traits, sqlx

I've got this code that matches a type coming from an unknown sqlx query. In the example, it's PgRow and I want to transform it into an `enum MyDynamicValue` depending on the `type_info`. I could implement it for every type defined by every databases and add an entry in the `match`. I think that you can see that it's a lot repetitive.

```rust
fn get_row_value(row: &PgRow, col_index: usize) -> Result<Option<MyDynamicValue>> {
    let value_ref = row
        .try_get_raw(col_index)
        .map_err(|err| Error::RunQueryError)?;
    Ok(match value_ref.type_info().name() {
        "VARCHAR" => row
            .try_get::<Option<String>, usize>(col_index)
            .map_err(|err| Error::RunQueryError)?
            .map(|value| MyDynamicValue::String(value)),
        "INT4" => row
            .try_get::<Option<i32>, usize>(col_index)
            .map_err(|err| Error::RunQueryError)?
            .map(|value| MyDynamicValue::Integer(value)),
        "BYTEA" => row
            .try_get::<Option<&[u8]>, usize>(col_index)
            .map_err(|err| Error::RunQueryError)?
            .map(|value| MyDynamicValue::Bytea(value.to_owned())),
            // ...
        name => panic!("UNHANDLED DATABASE TYPE: {name}"),
    })
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
pub enum MyDynamicValue {
    String(String),
    Integer(i32),
    Bytea(Vec<u8>),
}
```

The parts that I want to refactor is:

```rust
        "VARCHAR" => row
            .try_get::<Option<String>, usize>(col_index)
            .map_err(|err| Error::RunQueryError)?
            .map(|value| MyDynamicValue::String(value)),
```

And I would like to only write:

```rust
row.try_get(col_index).into()
```

The problem is that I match on `type_info.name()` to know the type of the output.

Anyway, I'm not sure about good pratices and if someone can lighten the path, I'll gladly follow.

I tried a few things always lead to me realizing I was in over my head.

I tried implementing `From<dyn Decode<'a, T, DB>>`: compiler was not happy.

How can I make this code less repetitive?

Bonus question: How can I even do it for any database type?

Comment: I don't think there is a better option. To be generic over the database, you can do something similar to `#[serde(untagged)]` by trying each variant (which can also be generalized to a proc macro if you have a lot of types), but this will be much less efficient.

Comment: Can you add some pseudo code which shows how it should look like. The code you want to be refactored can be refactored using macros, either procedural or declarative. But I am at least not sure what you expect. Writing short code would be something different than code which is good for maintenance or maybe "good practice" or a code which can be used for any types.

Comment: @trust_nickol I modified it a little bit and only changed `map_err` and `map` into `try_into` but I wish I had a cleaner way to refacto the `try_get` as well.